# Google cloud VM add pgAdmin geting error Unable to connect to server: timeout expired

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postgresql

I am connecting my pgAdmin with the VM of google cloud.

first I create VM instances after that the public IP address of VM instances I use pgAdmin hostname and when I try to save than getting an error **Unable to connect to server: timeout expired**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the community tutorial [How to set up PostgreSQL on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres):

> This tutorial shows how to set up PostgreSQL on Google Cloud Platform
> (GCP) in just a few minutes. Follow this tutorial to configure
> PostgreSQL on an Ubuntu virtual machine instance on Compute Engine.
>
> If you don't want to install and manage your own PostgreSQL database,
> [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres) provides managed PostgreSQL.
>
> You can also use [Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/?q=postgres) to set up PostgreSQL on Compute
> Engine with just a few clicks.

You should follow steps below:

1. Create VM instance.
2. Install PostgreSQL and use PSQL to complete the setup.
3. Configure PostgreSQL remote access:
   3.1. edit `pg_hba.conf`:

   - navigate to [ip4.me](http://ip4.me/) to get the IPv4 address of your local computer;
   - scroll down to the bottom of the file and add the following lines:

     ```
     # IPv4 remote connections for the tutorial:
     host    all             all           [YOUR_IPV4_ADDRESS]/32         md5
     ```
   - replace [YOUR_IPV4_ADDRESS] with the address of your local computer;
   - save the file and exit the editor.
     3.2. edit `postgresql.conf`:
   - scroll down to the line that begins with `#listen_addresses = 'localhost'`;
   - delete the `#` character to uncomment the line;
   - replace `localhost` with `*` (the '*' setting enables Postgres to listen on all IP addresses);
   - save the file and exit the editor;
   - restart the database service.
4. [Set network tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags#adding_new_tags_to_vm_instances) `postgresql-server` to your VM instance:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances add-tags instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-a -- tags=postgresql-server
   ```
5. [Create new firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/configuring-firewall#creating_a_firewall_ingress_rule) to allow incoming connections:

   ```
   gcloud compute firewall-rules create postgresql-server-rule-in --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:5432 --target-tags=postgresql-server
   ```
6. Connect using pgAdmin:

- in the Host field, enter external IP address of your VM instance;
- in the Port field, enter 5432.

As an alternative, you can follow documentation [18.11. Secure TCP/IP Connections with SSH Tunnels](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssh-tunnels.html):

> It is possible to use SSH to encrypt the network connection between
> clients and a PostgreSQL server. Done properly, this provides an
> adequately secure network connection, even for non-SSL-capable
> clients.

Comment: I am getting the error. I inter my IP address in `IPv4 local connections:` and `# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'  # what IP address(es) to listen on;`

Comment: I am using PostGIS database as backend

Comment: Please follow the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres) and update your question with your steps. configuration files, commands and error messages to make me able to troubleshoot your setup.